# How does setState not work in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a post request and setting the state on a object on the response received. I need the data to be used so that I can map it and display it on a dropdown.

Tried using `length` and did not work.

**State in the component:**

```
this.state = {
    assignees: []
};
```

**The API request:**

```
axios
.post("http://localhost:3600/get_assignees", {
    id: id
})
.then(res => {
    this.setState({ assginees: res.data });
});
```

**Destructuring:**

```
const { assginees } = this.state;
```

Mapped on a select element throws `Cannot read property length of undefined`

```
<select className="Dropdown"
        name="assginees"
        defaultValue={"DEFAULT"} > {
        assginees.length
        ? assginees.map(item => (
            <option value={item} key={item}>
                {item.login}
            </option>
        ))
        : null }
</select>
```

The response structure is similar to the one received here 
`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators`

This is does to get the number of assignees available.

The state should be set when the data is received and I should be able to map it in the select option.

Comment: Do you mind showing the whole component?  it is unclear when each code snippet is called

Comment: When exactly do you assign the initial state? In the constructor or in some lifecycle method?

Comment: Initial state is `assignees` while all references later are `assginees`

Comment: Yikes, good ol' spelling mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
const {  assginees } = this.state;
```

you have state `assignees` and not `assginees` a typo here,

just change it to this,

```
 const {  assignees } = this.state;
```

```
{assignees.length > 0
    ? assignees.map(item => (
        <option value={item} key={item}>
           {item.login}
        </option>
     ))
: null}
```